# Deleting oldest record from localStorage

Tags: html, local-storage

I have a JS app that saves to localStorage. No big deal. However, what's being stored are fairly large JSONs. 10MB vanishes quickly. What I'd like to do is, if storage is full, delete the oldest record.

Is there a way to reliably find the oldest record in localStorage?

Comment: Not really, localStorage doesn't have any built-in functionality that would handle that. You could always build a layer on top of localStorage yourself; a layer that would extend localstorage to also keep track of when each key changed so that you could know which is the oldest record.

Comment: Ivan, you should turn that into an answer so I can mark it as correct. :) It looks like standard practice for a strict key/value db is what will work best here.

Comment: Sure thing, put it as an answer below. Btw. if you end up extending/wrapping localStorage to support this - open source it! I think there will be other people interested in it.

Comment: @IvanZuzak, I took your comment to heart: https://github.com/benjaminallison/SuperLocal

Comment: that's really cool! Glad you made the effort! Will check it out this week.

Comment: Thanks man! And of course, feel free to chime in on the repo if you notice my code sucks. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, localStorage doesn't have any built-in functionality that would handle that. You could always build a layer on top of localStorage yourself; a layer that would extend localStorage to also keep track of when each key changed so that you could know which is the oldest record.

Comment: Just finished this little library! Works pretty well! https://github.com/benjaminallison/SuperLocal

Answer (score 1):

You can do:
`localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(0));`

You specify in **localStorage.key** an integer to get the indexed key's name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with fetching/removing the *oldest* record.

Comment: Woops! I've just edited now! I thought he said about removing the last record. I ran the code and I'm pretty sure that it deletes the old record now.